# Rails 4 Strong Parameters Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a nested resource like the following: user/1/photos/new

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :photos, except: [:show]
end
```

My form_for is like the following:

```
= form_for([@user, @photo], html: { multipart: true }) do |f|

  .inputs
    = f.file_field :attached_photo

  .actions
    = f.submit :submit
```

I believe the problem I am having is with strong parameters:

```
   def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :attached_photo)
    end
```

When I hit the submit button on the form I get the following error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in PhotosController#create
param not found: photo

I'm using Paperclip so in the model I have:

```
has_attached_file :attached_photo
```

Please advise.

Comment: What does your rails server output show for params posted?

Comment: If I add a text field for the title. Then params are like the following: "photo"=>{"title"=>""}, "commit"=>"submit", "painter_id"=>"1" It seems :attached_photo isn't being passed.

Comment: Does the file not get passed even when you upload it with the file field? I tested with a paperclip photo upload on one of my applications, and it only includes the parameter if a file is actually selected with the file field.

Comment: So the problem is how to ensure that a photo is attached

Comment: Which model to you have the `has_attached_file :attached_photo` code in?

Comment: It's in a Photo model. A User can have many Photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that a user uploads a photo when submitting this form, then you should add a validation on the `Photo` model like so:

```
validates_attachment_presence :attached_photo
```

Then if the user does not upload a photo, the form will re-render telling the user to upload a photo.

You will also want to use this strong parameters code to make sure you do not have an error if the `photo` param does not exist:

```
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :attached_photo) if params[:photo]
end
```