# Paperclip: ActionController::ParameterMissing when attribute is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using the paperclip gem for image uploads and am having trouble getting it to display an error message when my `:photo` atrribute is not present.

My model is Image.rb:

```
validates_attachment :photo, :presence => true,
  :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/png"], :message => "must be a jpeg or png" },
  :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes, :message => "must be less than 1 MB" }
```

My controller create action:

```
  def create
    @images = Image.all
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    if @image.save
      redirect_to new_image_url, notice: 'Image uploaded.'
    else
      @image.errors.delete(:photo)
      render :new
    end
  end
```

When I submit the form without attaching an image, it raises an exception and shows the page:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ImagesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: image

    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:photo)
    end
```

I would except it to pass an error message to the errors hash like the rest of them, hence just displaying an error to `full_messages`.  But it is not doing that.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**  Adding form to upload

```
<%= simple_form_for @image, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @image.errors.any? %>
    <div class="panel panel-default border-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading background-color-danger"><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %>:</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.file_field :photo, error: false, input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>

  <hr />

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Upload", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

** I realize the `error: false` doesn't look good, but it just disables the simple_form inline errors.  That isn't the problem.

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

Based on the accepted answer, here is my new create action and strong parameters which I've used to form a viable solution to this problem.

*ImagesController.rb  #create*

```
  # POST /images
  def create
    @images = Image.all
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    if params[:image]
      if @image.save
        redirect_to new_image_path, notice: 'Photo uploaded.'
      else
        @image.errors.delete(:photo)
        render :new
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_image_path, alert: 'Photo cannot be blank.'
    end
  end
```

*Strong params*

```
def image_params
  params.require(:image).permit(:photo) if params[:image]
end
```

Comment: please post your view to upload

Comment: One one the possible reasons could be that the `params[:image]` is not being sent to server. Like Rajarshi said, can you please post your relevant view code?

Comment: added the upload form.  the "view" just includes the form.  thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347619/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-resource), this should work:

```
def image_params
  params.require(:image).permit(:photo) if params[:image]
end
```

Comment: Excellent, this did work and I updated my create action.  I've posted my new create action in my OP.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I found something that can help you; check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626377/change-error-validation-message-in-paperclip).

I'm also using the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem in my app. if an `:image`, or in your case `:photo`, is not attached you get an error message "Image can't be blank".

All I did is this:

**Image** model:

```
has_attached_file :photo
validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
validates :photo, presence: true
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I had indeed already tried including a separate validates as you do above and even overriding the paperclip default validations as the link suggests. However, I had no luck.  It still doesn't display "image cannot be blank" - it raises the error I had in my OP.